# Facebook High Scores Server

Tags: facebook

I want to merge my High Scores with facebook.
In other words, I don't want to mantain my own score server but I would like to let make the dirt work to facebook.

So I want to publish new scores and retrieve them to display in my game.

Can I do it? What API can I use? Is it possible with REST?

**EDIT**: Many games in fb show global scores & friends score. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write data to fb with this: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Data_Store_API_documentation

However, i'd reccomend using a more stable mature platform like Google app engine. Facebook's API's have been extremely flaky lately, and when I was using the facebook datastore, I'd often find it to be slow and even worse, return inconsistent results.